# Can you load the map in a 'Practice match' to test your settings?

Tags: pubg-battlegrounds

My computer has been having a hard time running PUBG (it's starting to get ancient) so I'm trying different settings to see what works best for my computer.

But every time I want to try a setup, I have to get into a real match, wait the minute buffer (I get in at maybe 20 seconds left, but still), Get on the plane, jump down, and then I'll have an idea what my settings do in terms of performance.

So is there a way to load the map, or at least load a test range where I can see my probable FPS before jumping into a real game?

Comment: On that topic, PUBG has a big problem of trying to load too much stuff at the same time. I fought with it all morning trying to find a solution, but basically, as soon as I look up after landing my disk usage goes to 100% and stays there. Think I need a new computer if I want to play PUBG.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly there is no "practice mode" available to the public yet, although there are **custom matches**.

In order to **create** a custom match you must be verified by PlayerUnknown, which will most likely only happen if you are either a streamer or company that would promote the game.

You can **join** a custom match by clicking on "custom match" after hovering over the  play butten in the top right. Custom matches do not count towards your rank so it doesn't matter if you die right away while you're testing your fps. Even after you die you can still spectate the players and test your PCs performance that way.
[image]